# What is the name and value of the constant that relates to electrons and that coincidentally has the same exact value as the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, electrons

There's some constant relating to electrons that also has the same value as the speed of light. What is it, what is the value, and how are they related?

EDIT: Is it the fine-structure constant?? Are there any other similar constants? If you posted that answer before, you shoulda left it (to the person who deleted their answer)!

Comment: What is the value of a constant that has exact the same value as the speed of light? Well, isn't that obvious? ;)

The question is rather vague.

Comment: Wait, I just have to find my mind-reading device then I'll tell you...

Comment: lol.. but isn't there ONLY one such constant? I just can't recal what it's called... but it's very interesting!

Comment: -1 ... aaaarghh

Comment: hahaha.. well too bad my reputation can't go below 1. ;)

Comment: Sorry, but this is _really_ not a well posed question. If you can edit it to be clear and specific enough, I'd be happy to reopen it. (If you just want to know about the fine structure constant, take a look at the Wikipedia article.)

Answer (score 3):

The constant you are looking for is not related to electrons, but to electromagnetics. From the Wikipedia article 'Speed of light':

"The classical behaviour of the electromagnetic field is described by Maxwell's equations, which predict that the speed c with which electromagnetic waves (such as light) propagate through the vacuum is related to the electric constant ε0 and the magnetic constant μ0 by the equation c = 1/√ε0μ0."